# How can I continuously update the range of the x axis in d3 graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a continuously increasing value that I would like to adapt the range of my d3 graph to. I can change the range of the x axis using

```
xScale.domain([a, b]);
```

but this does not seem to be capable of multiple updates of the x axis scale. How can I continuously change the x axis range?

Comment: what do you mean by `multiple updates of the x axis scale`? it should update your `xScale` every time you call it. You will still need to update your rendering logic after updating `xScale`, like redrawing your visualization with the updated positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps needed to update an axis are:

1. Update the scale:

   ```
   xScale = xScale.domain([a, b]);
   ```
2. Update the axis with the new scale:

   ```
   domXAxis.call(xAxis.scale(xScale));
   ```

   This update can also be animated:

   ```
   domXAxis.transition()
       .duration(animationDurationMs)
       .call(xAxis.scale(xScale));
   ```